# how to make the filed Integer of java object null to null in sql instead 0

Tags: java, null, integer

Here is my modele

```
@Entity
public class Structure implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer idt_structure;
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idt_parent_structure")
private Structure structure;

// Getters and setters
}
```

Example of input and outpu

**Input**

```
    public void save(){
    Structure structure = new Structure();
    structure.setName("structure");
    structure.setStructure(null);
    structureService.add(structure);
    }
```

Here is my Service

```
Transactional
@Service("structureService")
public class StructureServiceImpl implements IStructureService{


@Autowired
@Qualifier("structureDao")
private StructureDao structureDao;

private List<Structure> structures;

public StructureServiceImpl() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void addStructure(Structure structure) {
    structureDao.save(structure);
}
// getters and setters
}
```

Here is My DAO

```
@Repository
public class StructureDao extends GenericDaoHibernateImpl<Structure, Integer> {


@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public StructureDao(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory);
}
}
```

SQL SCHEMA TABLE Structure idt_structure int(11), name varchar(255), idt_parent_structure int(11). And all columns All columns can take the value null unless idt_structure

**Output in datadase**

sql schema : idt_structure, name , idt_parent_structure.

structure(1,name,0);

**and i want to have output like this**

structure(1,name,null);

The default value of an Integer is 0 And I want to have null in sql database for the idt_parent_structure column.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What is your database schema? How do you store the data in the DB? How do you generate the output? etc.

Comment: Why do you want to see `null` in id field? In most cases it would be wrong

Comment: @assylias thank u for ur reply i update my post to  see more details.

Comment: please add `structureDao.save`, configuration of your ORM and DB schema. DB schema and configuration is important since it depends on not only code

Comment: @ADS i'm using GenericDaoHibernateImpl it's generic but u can see i update my post

Answer (score 0):

Since you write `@GeneratedValue` you [don't manage what exactly id would be](http://javabeat.net/jpa-annotations-generatedvalue-sequencegenerator-tablegenerator/).

---

Provide us complete example and we'll help you

Comment: thank for ur reply but not the id i want to have null in the idt_parent_structure

Comment: @Rodik I can't  understand you. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: Ok, I have a structure object that contains a parent object of the same type tt the time of inserting the structure object, I enter the name of this structure and If I select parent object the idt_parent_structure column in sql takes the id of the selected objet. In the second case If I don't select parent object when inserting The value of idt_parent_structure takes 0. And i want to have null not 0.